# Adding multiple shapes on an image/canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to build an image using predefined shapes such as circle, triangle, star etc.

For example, a webpage is divided on the left and right. On the left is an image of a T-shirt. On the right are images of shapes. User can drag and drop shapes on the T-Shirt image.

When the user saves the image, we want to save one image composed of the shapes on the T-Shirt image.

Is HTML canvas a good solution for this, or is it achievable using any JavaScript library?

Comment: @freginold i am looking for a javascript solution.

Comment: @chanchal118 Making shapes in HTML5 Canvas is pretty trivial. Here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen main issue here is making one final using from the final composition and drag and drop of the shapes to another image. What do you suggest for that? Canvas or any javascript library?

Comment: A javascript library using Canvas? For instance @m0ns1f answers: [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/). In general i think that answer, answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `canvas` is a great solution , and would give client a great user-experience,

and you can achieve that using `jquery`+ [`Fabricjs`](http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js),

see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/hGj3j/)